# Animate a path?

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a set of coordinates. I would like to take, for instance, the first 5 and draw a line connecting 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 to 5. Then after a pre-determined duration, I'd like to remove the first point and add the 6th point. In doing that, I'd like the line to animate in such a way as the "beginning" of the line moves from point 1 to point2, while the end of the line moves from point 5 to point 6.

The effect here would look a lot like the old game Nibbles with the snake that moves around eating stuff.

What would be the most efficient way to approach this in WPF?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to post a rough outline of my solution here. I actually ended up using a [PathGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingpath.pathgeometry.aspx) object and a set of [DoubleAnimationUsingPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingpath.aspx) animations to get what I wanted. Polyline (suggested by Damokles) got me going in the right direction, but it wasn't until I found the [DoubleAnimationUsingPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingpath.aspx) class that I was able to take it where I wanted to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Polyline and manipulate the Points collection by simply adding and removing the points.
See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline.points.aspx) for example code.