# Animate a path like it's drawn on a canvas

Tags: wpf, animation, path, draw

I'm a newbie in WPF and please, guide me in the right direction for this problem.

I have built a WPF application which contains all the functionality of that of a road map view control. I.e. the road map can be zoomed in/out, panned in all directions using mouse, keyboard and the controls provided. I have mapped the roads as paths drawn using Expression Blend.

Currently I am looking for a way to animate a selected road, as if it was drawn by a pencil/pen/marker. Is this possible? So far, I've been able to animate the opacity and color of the path. I've search a lot for this functionality with no luck. May be I do not search for the correct terms. I hope someone of you could shed some light on to this matter.

Thanks in advance. Am sorry, if I sound crazy :) Programming is my way of being crazy :D

Comment: I don't quite understand, have you been able to animate opacity and color or not? If yes, it should be easy for you to also animate e.g. the StrokeThickness.

Comment: I have animated the opacity and color. Animating StrokeThickness is not a problem too, although it is not what i need. Imagine there are two points connected in a complex line (curved lines + straight lines). Now imagine that path is invisible and you are drawing that path using a pencil. I want to achieve this effect. Did I help you understand?

Comment: Not really. Aren't you already drawing the path (with an arbitrarily complex geometry) with a certain pen (defined by stroke properties).

Comment: I have the path data. I am not drawing the path, just specifying the path data will just render it WITHOUT an animation. I want animate this path point to point when rendering. So the user will see it as if it is drawn from point A to B over a given duration. I cannot explain any simpler :(

Comment: @both: I got it :) But I don't have a solution for it. Have just tested something in blend, but it doesn't seem to have that functionality out of the box.
But here's a similar issue, perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876806/animate-a-path

Comment: @Hawkz Coud you update your question with some sample paths you'd like to animate along? Trash your WPF exerience as it's a logica opposed to a technological type of challenge:)

Comment: This example looks very promising:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/19a7bd4b-cf28-4b31-a329-a5f58b9ec374

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: We take advantage of the `PointAnimationUsingPath`. We animate a point along the path and build a `Clip` geometry as the point is moving.**

---

**Full answer:**

I start by drawing a sample `Path` in a `Grid` for demonstration purposes. Put the actual `Path` data in resources because we will re-use it later.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="path">
            <PathFigure>
                <BezierSegment Point1="10 30" Point2="100 100" Point3="200 10" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Path x:Name="myPath" StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Black" Data="{StaticResource path}" />
</Grid>
```

Then I define an empty `Clip` geomtery for the `Path`:

```xml
<Path.Clip>
    <GeometryGroup x:Name="geometryGroup" FillRule="Nonzero"/>
</Path.Clip>
```

So far, the `Path` disappeared because it is clipped to an empty geometry. What we have left to do is progressively add points back in this clipping geometry to reveal the `Path`.
For that, we need an object to animate. I suggest to create a `FrameworkPoint` for the demonstration:

```cs
public class FrameworkPoint : FrameworkElement {
    public static DependencyProperty CenterProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Center", typeof(Point), typeof(FrameworkPoint));
    public Point Center { get => (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty); set => SetValue(CenterProperty, value); }

    public event Action<Point> CoordinatesChanged;

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        if (e.Property == CenterProperty) {
            CoordinatesChanged?.Invoke(Center);
        }
    }
}
```

This is an object with only one property of type `Point`, and this property is *animatable*. Let's add our (invisible) point in the `Grid` and animate it on our `Path`:

```xml
<local:FrameworkPoint x:Name="myPoint">
    <local:FrameworkPoint.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <PointAnimationUsingPath Duration="00:00:10"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Center"
                                             PathGeometry="{StaticResource path}"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </local:FrameworkPoint.Triggers>
</local:FrameworkPoint>
```

At start-up, the `FrameworkPoint` will invisibly follow the `Path` over the indicated time (10 seconds). All is left to do is build our `Clip` as the point moves:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        myPoint.CoordinatesChanged += MyPoint_CoordinatesChanged;
    }

    private void MyPoint_CoordinatesChanged(Point obj) {
        geometryGroup.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry(obj, 5, 5));
    }
}
```

This won't give perfect results for fast animations because the sampling won't be good enough but it could give you ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if this is what you are looking for, but I'll give it a shot.

The animation would be a bit complex. It would actually be a series of animations, one for each point in your path minus the first point. You would want to add point to the animated path, one at a time, from the source path. Each time you add a point, that point starts at the previous point, and travels to the desired point. The animation would move the newly added point along over time, giving the effect of that segment being "drawn". When that animation completes, you iterate to your next point and begin the next animation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't won't it to be amidst of comments, here's a great post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/19a7bd4b-cf28-4b31-a329-a5f58b9ec374

and here's is Charles Petzold's take on the problem:

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/08/150351.html