# Animate a Beziersegment in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, bezier

I have a simple BezierSegment with a StartPoint, 2 controls points and an EndPoint.

[image]

The XAML for this is:

```xml
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" x:Name="MySegment">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="100,100">
                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                        <BezierSegment Point1="135,100" Point2="135,125" Point3="100,125"/>
                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

But now I want to "draw" it from the start point to the end point (like a line's `X1` and `X2` properties into a Storyboard).

```xml
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" To="350"/>
```

I found some examples with `PointAnimation` but in my case I don't want to change a point's position, **I just want to draw the line between Start-Point1-Point2-End**.

Thank's to all who are going to help me!

Comment: Can you show a short sample XAML with your Bezier curve?

Comment: I made a pastebin with the xaml code: [pastbin](https://pastebin.com/A5dLeX7p)

Comment: See the first link in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833089/1136211

Comment: @Luca_8 you can see [my new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62882705/12067560) to the post Clemens has linked.